# How to take progress update and turn into a progress bar?

Tags: python, while-loop, progress-bar, google-speech-api

I'm using a speech-to-text API and while waiting for the results I'm able to print the current percentage of progress with this:

```
    while not operation.done():
        print(operation.metadata.progress_percent)
        time.sleep(5)
    print(operation.metadata.progress_percent)
```

And get this:

```
    0
    2
    3
    ...
```

How can i turn it into a progress bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress bar in python curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011314/progress-bar-in-python-curses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can end the line of a print statement with a carriage return, `\r`, to overwrite the current line, and use that to continually "update" the progress bar.

An example of printing a progress bar:

```py
import time

def progress_bar(progress, total=100, bar_length=20):
  # How much of the bar should be filled
  fill = progress * bar_length // total
  # How much of the bar should be empty
  empty = bar_length - fill
  print(f'[{"#"*fill}{"-"*empty}]', end='\r')
  # Go to next line if done
  if progress == total:
    print()

# Emulate a percentage progress
for i in range(0, 101):
  progress_bar(i)
  time.sleep(0.05)
```

This will output a bar that looks like this

```
[##############------]
```